# Change text of a TextView Layout inside spinner adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-spinner

I have layout that contains a TextView which I am using in a spinner. How to change `android:text` at the runtime depending on my spinner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:textSize="18sp"
  android:textColor="#808080"
  android:text="@string/month"/>
```

Comment: findViewById(R.id.text1).setText("Some new text");

is this what you are looking for? your question is not very clear

Comment: what is not clear please specify.

Comment: you text view is designed to display some text that you chose inside the spinner ?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to find the text of the currently selected item in the spinner, and then setting it to another textview this is what you  need to do

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.idOfSpinner);
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView);

textView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: please don't answer if you don't understand the question.